# Mailgun.Attachment is not a constructor

Tags: email, pdf, attachment, email-attachments, mailgun

I am sending PDF attachment by using mailgun.  When create an instance .
Const attch = new mailgun.Attachment({data:file, filename:filename, contentType: application/PDF});
And run the API it does returned error. "Mailgun.Attachment is not a constructor"